# Create country borders image inside a specific area

Tags: python, countries

I have an array of latitudes and longitudes like this:

```
arr =
[[[52.451466,  8.669105]
  [52.450689,  8.683759]
  [52.449911,  8.698414]
  ...
  [49.358081, 29.464242]
  [49.354822, 29.477067]
  [49.351562, 29.489892]]

 [[52.442744,  8.667857]
  [52.441966,  8.682509]
  [52.441187,  8.69716 ]
  ...
  [49.349625, 29.459223]
  [49.346366, 29.472047]
  [49.343107, 29.48487 ]]]
```

which defines a polygon like this one:

[image]

The polygon segments or edges are `arr[0]` for the top, `arr[-1]` bottom, `arr[:, 0]` left and `arr[:, -1]` right.
The polygon corners or vertices are `arr[0][0]`, `arr[0][-1]`, `arr[-1][0]`, `arr[-1][-1]`.

How can I create an image of country borders having this array? Please note that it is not a perfect rectangle. Also, the country name or other informations are not important, only the borders.

Comment: What does the `countries` tag refer to?

Comment: What is a country border? What image or graphics module do you plan on using?