# Find closest point in a 2D array of polygon points

Tags: python, numpy, search

I have a 2D array of geo coordinates, like this

```
coords = np.array(
[[[54.496163, 21.770491],
  [54.495438, 21.755107],
  [54.494713, 21.739723],
  [54.493988, 21.724339],
  [54.493263, 21.708955]],
 [[54.504881, 21.769271],
  [54.504157, 21.753884],
  [54.503432, 21.738497],
  [54.502707, 21.72311 ],
  [54.501983, 21.707723]],
 [[54.5136, 21.768052],
  [54.512875, 21.752661],
  [54.512151, 21.737271],
  [54.511426, 21.72188 ],
  [54.510702, 21.70649 ]],
 [[54.522318, 21.766832],
  [54.521594, 21.751439],
  [54.52087, 21.736045],
  [54.520145, 21.720651],
  [54.519421, 21.705257]],
 [[54.531037, 21.765613],
  [54.530312, 21.750216],
  [54.529588, 21.734819],
  [54.528864, 21.719421],
  [54.52814, 21.704024]]]
)
```

In space it defines a polygon
[image: img]

I want to find the index of the closest point in `coords` of a certain point, for example `pt = [54.5, 21.7]`

`coords` may look like a parallelogram here, but in reality it is a polygon of shape `(1200, 1500, 2)`. Here I am displaying `coords[0:5,0:5]` for obvious reasons.
The real shape of the polygon can be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220788/create-country-borders-image-inside-a-specific-area?noredirect=1#comment100947996_57220788).

Right now I am calculating the euclidean distance of the entire `coords` array relative to the point `pt` to find the closest point, at `[r1,c1]`

```
flidx = ((coords - pt) ** 2).sum(2).argmin()
r1 = int(flidx / coords.shape[1])
c1 = flidx % coords.shape[1]
```

but this takes too much time.

I am thinking of implementing a binary search in the polygon, where I can separate it in 4 parts, check in which part the point is inside, and loop until I have a relatively small array of points, 16 by 16 for instance. Then apply the euclidean distance method.

The problem is that I do not know how to check if a point is inside a polygon. A rectangle would be fairly easy but this is not one.

Any help with this method, or with any other method to find the closest point would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: what exactly do you mean by polygon? it looks like a lattice under a linear transform. Will the points always be grid-like?

Comment: You are already using array functions, so it might give you no big speed gain, but you could try the second version of the answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28207/finding-the-closest-point-to-a-list-of-points).

Comment: @VersBersch  The real shape can be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220788/create-country-borders-image-inside-a-specific-area?noredirect=1#comment100947996_57220788)
Look at the green polygon in the image.
Yes it is grid like.

Comment: @ErgiS in your link the data looks like a grid of lat/long points. i.e. the raw data forms a square grid (perhaps rotated a bit) and the "distortion" to the shape comes from mapping lat/long coordinates onto a 2D surface. So is there this distortion in the underlying data itself or does it come from the mapping?

Comment: @VersBersch the distortion comes from the data, not its projection onto a 2D surface.

Comment: @ErgiS - okay, well for some point X, finding the closest point to X on a grid is easy, and finding the closest point to X in a set or arbitrary points is hard(er) / will need a more robust algorithm. If you know how the points are generated then you can perhaps use the easy grid-search method, you just need to know how to transform your points into a grid (which is possible if they represent some projection of lat / long points). Perhaps you can share the entire dataset?

Comment: @VersBersch Can you please share a link for the easy grid-search algorithm? The data-set can be found here [file](https://ufile.io/kjd5avpg). You need to install `netcdf4` for python
```
lon = Dataset("coords.nc")["longitude_in"][:]
lat = Dataset("coords.nc")["latitude_in"][:]
coords = np.dstack([lat, lon])
```

According to the documentation, the scaling factor is 1e-6

Comment: [Documentation](https://sentinel.esa.int/documents/247904/1872792/Sentinel-3-SLSTR-Product-Data-Format-Specification-Level-1)

Answer (score 2):

First note that the data is not a perfect grid, but it is "grid-like"

```py
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

group = Dataset('./coords.nc', 'r', format='NETCDF4')

# reverse the input so that the bottom left point is at [0, 0]
lat = np.array(group['latitude_in'])[::-1]
lon = np.array(group['longitude_in'])[::-1]

# plot a sub-grid
slat = np.array([arr[::100] for arr in lat[::100]]).flatten()
slon = np.array([arr[::100] for arr in lon[::100]]).flatten()
plt.scatter(slat, slon)
plt.show()
```

[image: 12 x 15 sub-grid of the data]

To find the coordinates of the closest point in the set to some target point, you can get a reasonable approximation (an initial guess for your search) by doing a "change of basis". I.e. if the vector from the bottom left to bottom right is your x-direction, and bottom left to top-left is the y-direction vector, applying a change of basis matrix will map the points to the unit square (not perfectly). Then you can work out the relative coordinates.

Then to finish, you can just walk along the grid (starting from the initial guess) towards the direction of the target point (i.e. move to whichever neighbour is closest)

```py
import itertools

class NearestIndex:
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = points 
        self.size = np.array(self.points.shape[:2]) - 1  # 1199 x 1499

        self.origin = points[0][0]  # origin must be at [0, 0]
        dX = points[-1, 0] - self.origin # the X-direction
        dY = points[0, -1] - self.origin # the Y-direction
        self.M = np.linalg.inv(np.array([dX, dY])) # change of basis matrix

    def guess(self, target):
        """ guess the initial coordinates by transforming points to the unit square """
        p = map(int, self.size * np.matmul(target - self.origin, self.M))
        return np.clip(p, 0, self.size)  # ensure the initial guess is inside the grid

    def in_grid(self, index):
        return (index == np.clip(index, 0, self.size)).all()

    def distance_to_target(self, index):
        return np.linalg.norm(self.points[index] - self.target)

    def neighbour_distances(self, index):
        i, j = index
        min_dist = np.inf
        min_index = None       
        for di, dj in itertools.product((-1, 0, 1), repeat=2):
            neighbour = (i + di, j + dj)
            if not (di == dj == 0) and self.in_grid(neighbour):
                dist = self.distance_to_target(neighbour)
                if dist < min_dist:
                    min_dist, min_index = dist, neighbour

        return min_index, min_dist

    def find_nearest(self, target):
        self.target = target
        index = self.guess(target)  # make an initial guess
        min_dist = self.distance_to_target(index)  # distance to initial guess
        while True:
            # check the distance to the target from each neighbour of index
            neighbour, dist = self.neighbour_distances(index)
            if dist < min_dist:
                index, min_dist = neighbour, dist
            else:
                return index, min_dist
```

Use it like this

```py
points = np.dstack([lat, lon])
indexer = NearestIndex(points)
index, dist = indexer.find_nearest(np.array([46, 15])) 

print(index, coords[index], dist)  # (546, 556) [46.004955 14.999708] 0.004963596377623203
```

It's already pretty speedy, but there's plenty of room for optimization too. You could memoize function `distance_to_target`, or use different step sizes in the walk toward the point.

Answer (score 1):

If you rearrange your point array, I think you can use [shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/):

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon

point = Point(0.5, 0.5)
polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
print(polygon.contains(point))
```

I'm not completely sure about the speed, but it should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can also compute the euclidian distance and find the right index with `unravel_index`:

```
import numpy as np

pt = [54.5, 21.7]

#Distance for each coordinate sqrt((ptx-x)^2+(pty-y)^2)
dis = ((pt[0]-coords[:,:,0])**2+(pt[1]-coords[:,:,1])**2)**0.5
#Get the x,y index
ind = np.unravel_index(dis.argmin(), dis.shape)
#Get the coordinate
val = coords[ind[0],ind[1],:]
```